# What is the correct way to call a function which accepts a multidimensional array as a parameter (one of type int[][] for example)?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I don't understand what is the correct way to call a function which accepts  a multidimensional array as a parameter(a parameter of type `int[][]` for example).

The function's form is

```
public static int llamarArreglo(int[][] array){  ...  }
```

I tried to  call the function from within the main class by creating an array, and then trying to print a specific slot in the array, and it should print a 1 (because function 'llamarArreglo' fills an array with 1s the diagonal, and the rest of the slots is 0):

```
int[][] arr = new int[3][3];

System.out.print(llamarArreglo(arr[2][1]));
```

This is not compiling correctly, code inside the function works if I evaluate it in main class, without using a function/method. I beleive that I am not understanding how to call the function from the main class.
If you prefer to look at the complete, minimal code, there it is:

```
public class ArreglosMultidimensionales {

  public static int llamarArreglo(int[][] array) {

      int i;
      int j;
    for(i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        for(j=0; j<array[i].length; j++){

            if (i == j) {
            array[i][j]=1;
        }else {
            array[i][j] = 0;
        }


        }

        }
    }  

public static void main(String[] args) {

   int[][] arr = new int[3][3];


   System.out.print(llamarArreglo(arr[2][1]));


              }      

}
```

Thanks, if there is such help.

Comment: `arr[2][1]` is not a 2d array, it is an `int`. Pass `arr` instead?

Comment: @Mango changing to `arr` is not the problem. The program still doesn't compile.

Comment: If you don't show us the error message, how do you expect anyone to help you?

Comment: @JimGarrison Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - missing return statement

Comment: It won't compile because your missing a return statement at the end of your code. If you don't want to return anything make the method void.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this: `llamarArreglo(arr)` like below.

```
public class ArreglosMultidimensionales {
    public static void llamarArreglo(int[][] array) {
        int i;
        int j;
        for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {

                if (i == j) {
                    array[i][j] = 1;
                } else {
                    array[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] arr = new int[3][3];
        llamarArreglo(arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that. But the program still doesn't compile.

Comment: output says: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - missing return statement

Comment: ah, yes, it compiles